# Could it be made possible to add Teams to the "Your communities" list?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, stack-overflow-for-teams, communities-list

I'm talking about the list that can be opened at the top right:

[image]

It would be nice if it would be possible to add Teams that one is part of to this list. Currently, searching for the team name does not give any results. As you can see, I don't have Stack Overflow in my list because I'm not an active user there — in that situation, getting to a Team is complicated (mainly on the mobile site (i.e. not the app), where using history is less easy).

Comment: I'm pretty sure the "can you" answer is "no" because teams are part of SO, so you might just kill that part of the question and focus on the FR. :) Also, since the App doesn't recognize Teams at all, it'd sort of break the app slightly, which it already kinda does.

Comment: I don't think its unnecessary because your team link is right on stackoverflow.

Comment: @JonH like I wrote, "I don't have Stack Overflow in my list because I'm not an active user there — in that situation, getting to a Team is complicated."

Comment: @Keelan you have over 5k rep on stackoverflow - so my point is...Teams is part of SO.  To get to your team get to SO.  To clutter this dropdown with ALL the teams you are on is a waste.

Comment: @JonH you can customise this list yourself. See the screenshot; I added the communities I used most. This is a feature request to have the *possibility* to add teams. This is not going to break anyone's workflow; you don't *have* to add teams. Why are you against this?

Comment: @Keelan - Right but teams are not communities...so it does break the workflow.  I am not against it - I don't think it makes sense.  Your COMMUNITY is SO, teams are not communities.  So you go to the SO community and there you will find your teams.